# Generate random var and then detect it using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a small project, where I would like to generate a random var based from multiple strings, and then further down choose another string based on the random var for earlier.

I'm not 100% if I've explained it perfectly, but I've created a sample version of the code below. I should state that in the actual code, there's close to 50 entries, rather than 3.

```
var fruits=['Apples','Bannanas','Pears']

var veg=['Potatoes','Carrots','Peas']

var fruitInfo=['This is an Apple','This is a Bannana','This is a pear']

fruit.innerHTML+=fruits[Math.round(Math.random()*(fruits.length-1))]+'\n';

veg.innerHTML+=veg[Math.round(Math.random()*(veg.length-1))]+'\n';
```

So, if it's unlear, I want to detect if an Apple has been selected and then state "This is an Apple" etc. I've also added in veg as there will be other random factors, however they won't need to be detected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your random selection is wrong. Use `Math.floor(Math.random()*fruits.length)` for uniform distribution.

Comment: Its unclear what you want to do? depluralize a word? prepend a fixed string to the random value? -  What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: I don't really see the point of having 2 arrays.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean...If the random number is 0, then it will choose 'Apples', and then in that case, you want the corresponding string in the `fruitInfo` array to be stated, correct? In that case, why not use an associate array?

Comment: @joshcawthorne You mean... something like this? `var whichFruit = Math.random(blablabla)*blablabla; fruits[whichFruit]; fruitInfo[whichFruit]; ...`

Comment: This seems like a great time to learn about [JavaScript Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to **create the random value and save in a variable** to use it repeatedly. And create another one for veggies (as I suppose you want different random for that).

```
    var fruits=['Apples','Bannanas','Pears']
    var veg=['Potatoes','Carrots','Peas']
    var fruitInfo=['This is an Apple','This is a Bannana','This is a pear']
    var random_num = Math.floor(Math.ran‌​dom()*fruits.length)
    fruit.innerHTML+=fruits[random_num]+'\n';
    fruitInfo.innerHTML+=fruitInfo[random_num]+'\n';
    var random_num2 = Math.floor(Math.ran‌​dom()*veg.length)
    veg.innerHTML+=veg[random_num2]+'\n';
```

Comment: Sorry, I've been playing around with this example you gave me and I can't get it to work; it doesn't ever display anything on the webpage. I'm sure it's just because I'm new to this, but could you show me where I'm going wrong?

Edit: Pressed enter before I added the code. I'll just add the link to it now.

Code example can be found here: http://codepaste.net/a2itm1

Comment: just go step by step. print out the `random_num` in console. If that's ok, print out `fruits[random_num]`. If that is also fine (what you expected), then you probably haven't declared `fruitInfo` object. `var fruitInfo = document.getElementById("fruitInfo")` should do the trick.

Comment: I've tried that, and it's still not working. I added an alert into my function to know when it's running, and the only time the function runs is when all of:

`var random_num2 = Math.floor(Math.ran‌​dom()*veg.length)

var fruitInfo = document.getElementB‌​yId("fruitInfo")

var random_num = Math.floor(Math.ran‌​dom()*fruits.length)`
aren't in the code. If they are, the chrome dev console says throws an error saying uncaught.

Comment: Update: It turns out that when I copied your example, some of the code, such as "random" was weirdly copied, throwing errors. Re-writing it out by hand seems to have sorted it. Thanks for your help!